# AirPrint multiple MVCs in swift

Tags: swift, forms, printing, airprint

I am building a form style app that allows the users to fill in textfields. once they fill up the page it will continue onto a second view. This will be about 5 pages worth of patient forms. when they get to the last page I want to have a print button that prints all 5 or 6 pages they have just filled out. I am trying to use the AirPrint code that I have recently found on here, but it will only let me do the current view.

```
extension UIView {
    func toImage() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

//        drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}


let pInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
pInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.general
pInfo.jobName = "Print Patient Forms"

          //Set up print controller
let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
printController.printInfo = pInfo

       //Assign a UIMage version of my UIView as a printing Item
printController.printingItem = self.view

var pInfo : UIPrintInfo = UIPrintInfo.printInfo()
pInfo.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientation.portrait

let formatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: textView.text!)

printController.showsNumberOfCopies = false
printController.showsPageRange = true

printController.printFormatter = formatter         printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
```

How do I go about letting this print all the pages?

Comment: "it will only let me do the current view"  That's because your code says printController.printingItem = self.view

Comment: I would concatenate all views vertically into one.

Comment: doing something like that... is it super complicated?

Comment: It should be super-easy.

Comment: El Tomato.... Could you point me in the right direction. I have searched all over the internet and cannot find anything hinting at combining storyboards for the last button before hitting print.

Comment: Create a singleton or use AppDelegate to save each view.  When combining all views, create an object with UIView.  Add each view in the singleton or AppDelegate to that object with addSubview method.